# How to start postgresql bundle

Tags: database, postgresql

How can I start postgresql from bundle, by googling It says command

> pg_ctl start [-D DATADIR]

but what path should I give in  datadir

no pg_hba.conf or folder nammed data in bundle like in installation

Comment: Which OS? This might be useful, for searching for the data-dirs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably [reference the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime.html).  You need to [run a command or two](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/creating-cluster.html) to initialize things before you can actually [start the server](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/server-start.html).